# ajax checkbox on post null

Tags: php, yii

The checkbox doesn't post, gives me `null`.

So what exactly makes a post not post? Sometimes I'm stuck at it and I not understanding when something is not set and doesn't get posted.

```
<?php echo CHtml::checkBox('markComplete', FALSE , array(
    'ajax' => array(
        'type'=>'POST',
        'id'=> $model->id,
        'url'=>$this->createUrl('complete',array('id'=>$model->id,))?>

public function actionComplete($id)
{
    $model= Model::model()->findbypk($id);

    if(isset($_POST['markComplete'])){
        $checkval = $_POST['markComplete']== true ? true : false;
        if($checkval == true){
            $model->status_id=7;
            $model->save(false);
        }
            echo $checkval;
    }
}
```

Comment: Checkboxes are only posted when checked but it seems you are already checking for that using `isset()`.

Comment: right, so when i clicked check, it's still not set. Not understanding why

Answer (score 0):

If a checkbox is not clicked, it is not included in `$_POST`.

So `if(isset($_POST['markComplete'))` means if the box was checked.

You don't need to pull the value from the checkbox unless you've specified it in that checkboxes `value=""` attribute.

Comment: but it never got pass that when i click on it. it gives me null.

Comment: Post your HTML in your question.

Comment: this is all i have `<input id="yt0" type="checkbox" value="1" name="markComplete">` or do i need a form?

Comment: yeah, put form tags around the input.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have specified your checkbox value to 'true', you code should be like below:

```
   if(isset($_POST['markComplete'])) {           
        if($checkval == 'your_checkbox_value') { // value you given for value attribute of checkbox
            $model->status_id=7;
            $model->save(false);
        }
        echo $checkval;
    }
```

Comment: Can you try doing a var_dump of post.var_dump($_POST);

Comment: please post what it gives when you do var_dump($_POST);
And are you sure you are passing the value in a post variable from client side if you do not have a form submit.
can you please also post your html and javascript/ajax functions you use for this.
Seems like you are not posting the checkbox value to server using the variable 'markComplete'.

Comment: It means nothing being posted from client side to sever through POST.
I am pretty sure now you are not submitting the form, neither posting that checkbox value through any ajax post variable.
If you can post your html and the javascript code, I could help you find the issues in the exact place.